# How to set default size for ng-view before angular load page in it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem. I have Index page where i load different pages in `<div ng-view></div>`.I have sidebar, so while im waiting that `ng-view` load page sidebar goes on left side and i dont want that.

In index i have `<div ng-view></div>` and right side menu:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="right-sidebar">

            @foreach (var item in Model.SideAccountBanners)
            {
                <div class="promo">
                    <a href="@item.LinkTo">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img class="resize" src="@item.BannerPath" alt="" />
                            <h1 class="title">@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(item.Title).Replace("-", "<br />"))</h1>
                            <p class="description">@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(item.Description).Replace("-", "<br />"))</p>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

How can i set default size for that `<div ng-view></div>` or set something like document ready? idk

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with css:

```
[ng-view] {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Something like the above.

EDIT: If you have multiple ng-views you will want to change the css.

Comment: Could you render your page and then past the HTML output so I can see what the structure looks like?

Comment: i can...but its too long

Comment: Just paste the top-level HTML structure underneath the body tag.

Comment: I have layout where i have  <div>
                @RenderBody()
            </div> and there i have index page which have ng-view

Comment: see my edit, it looks like the previous selector probably wasn't matching your needs